# ActiveAdmin lable name cant be singular

Tags: activeadmin

I am trying to get a singular label on my active admin but it keeps pluralizing the name

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: 'Article' do
```

I want the label on the screen to read 'Article' instead of 'Articles'

any way to make this happen?

http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you take a look at  https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md

you can do `menu label: 'Article'`

also to update the title on the index page  you can `do index title: 'Article' do`